# SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

Who knows as to connect it to the HTML form???

not to NewForm.aspx and to HTML form?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#State").SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList             : "SOGP",
            relationshipListParentColumn : "Title",
            relationshipListChildColumn  : "LC",
            parentColumn                 : "Title",
            childColumn                  : "LC"
        });
    });
</script>
<select id='State' listFieldName='Title' class='formInput'></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPServices' SPCascadeDropdowns isn't set up to work with any old arbitrary HTML. It's meant to be used with the default list forms.

(You already got this answer in the SPServices Discussions [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/576262).)